# How to pass named arguments into a Mix Task?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I have this code:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Echo do
  use Mix.Task

  @impl Mix.Task
  def run(args) do
    IO.puts("running!")
    Mix.shell().info(Enum.join(args, " "))
    IO.inspect(args, label: "Received args")
  end
end
```

Which can be used like this:

```
$ mix echo foo.bar 123
running!
foo.bar 123
Received args: ["foo.bar", "123"]
```

How to change the code so that I'd be able to pass **and get access to, by name** named arguments?

```
$ mix echo --arg1=123 --my_arg2="fdsafdsafds"
```

===>

```
Received args: %{"arg1" => 123, "my_arg2" => "fdsafdsafds"}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are searching for the [`OptionParser`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12.3/OptionParser.html#parse/2) module.

```elixir
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Echo do
  use Mix.Task

  @impl Mix.Task
  def run(args) do
    {parsed, _, _} = OptionParser.parse(args, strict: [my_arg1: :string, my_arg2: :boolean])
    IO.inspect(parsed, label: "Received args")
  end
end
```

This will give you a keyword list instead, which makes sense since it preserves order and allows for duplicate arguments. From there you can use `Enum.into/1` if you really need a map. You can also see that it allows for types.

Answer (score 0):

One can use literally any existing task in any existing project to check how is it done.

E. g. [`mix xref`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Xref.html) accepts arguments and [parses them](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.14.3/lib/mix/lib/mix/tasks/xref.ex#L286) with [`OptionParser`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/OptionParser.html).

**NB** the standard format of naming arguments to [elixir-mix](/questions/tagged/elixir-mix) is not `--foo=bar`, but `--foo bar`.

```bash
mix echo --arg1 123 --my_arg2 "fdsafdsafds"
```